# java lazy code after return using try - finally

Tags: java, return, try-finally

I have discovered possibility of having code "after return" using finally, here is some example:

```
int foo() {
    BufferedReader br = ...;
    try {
        // cca 20 lines with 4 returns in different if-else clauses etc
        //example:
        if(something) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

As (in my opinion much more lazy) alternativity to:

```
int foo() {
    BufferedReader br = ...;
    int toReturn;

    // cca 20 lines with 4 ASSIGMENTS in different if-else clauses etc
    //example:
    if(something) {
        toReturn = 0;
    } else {
        toReturn = 1;
    }

    br.close();
    return toReturn;
}
```

So, the question is, which is faster, more readable, and yes, in this case, i am really closing a BufferedReader, so is try-finnaly for this or am i using it wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using the `try/catch/finally`, if an exception is thrown, your `BufferedReader` won't be closed properly, causing a memory leak, potential unwanted file locking...

Using `finally`, your `BufferedReader` will be closed, even if an exception is thrown while processing the `try` block.

But as your `BufferedReader` instantiation can also throw an exception, you should include it in your `try` block:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = ...;
    // do your stuff
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
}
finally {
    if(br != null)
        br.close();
}
```

If you're using Java 7 or newer, go with the elegant [Try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), as stated by Arnaud.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an `exception` `throws`, both your code fail since first case you are not catching `exception` and second case there are no evidence of handling `exception`.

`finally` will execute any way here.

If your `BufferedReader` get input by file read, in a case which file not found both ways are not useful.

Answer (score 1):

> am i using it wrong way?

yes you are. What if say `something` is a method call and it throws exception, then **your br is never closed**. While finally makes sure that in any case it will get execute*

`* - there are some conditions where you can avoid finally clause execution

Answer (score 1):

The second one is actually unacceptable. You will not close the buffer in case of exception.

I advise you to use the **try-with-resources** statement (intended for that purpose):

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    //do what you want with the buffer. It will automatically be closed.
    return;
}
```

See [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Only with java 7 and up.